# Looking for Calendar app with alarm

Tags: calendars

I have a Nokia Lumia 920. I need a calendar with an alarm function to remind me of my appointments. Reminders such as SMS/Email don't work for me. Have tried several calendar apps, but none of them have an alarm (sound). They  only have reminders. HELP!

Answer (score 8):

The built in calendar has the ability to set reminders for appointments with sound notifications (that's what I use on my Lumia 920).

Just do the following:

- Open the calendar
- Hit the "+" button
- Enter your details, then scroll down and hit "More details"
- Then set the "Reminder" to whenever you'd like to be reminded.

In order to make sure your phone is set to play sounds for Reminders, do the following:

- Open up settings, then go to ringtones + sounds
- Tick the box "Play a sound for Reminders"

Comment: The problem is that this does a global alarm - I wan't to specify which appointments make a sound, e.g. like the Alarm, that overrides the silent setting on the phone.  (I've just upgraded to Windows Phone 8.1, but still can't see anything).